# Using python Download the latest file from s3 bucket inside folder not from inside folder --folder

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, boto

I want to download the latest file from s3-bucket inside folder only. Actually inside folder there are multiple folders along with files. But i need to download only file of latest date and upload it into one folder by selecting from multiple folders. I am referring the code from stackoverflow source code.

Here is structure of s3-bucket :

```
  S3-Bucket : --folder_1
                  --abc2022.01.29.csv
                  --bsv2022.02.18.csv
                  --test2022.03.04.csv
                  --Folder_12
                  --Folder_13
                  --folder_14
```

So basically, I want to download latest file from s3-bucket inside folder (folder_1) not from inside folder folders (Folder_12,Folder_13,Folder_14).

I am getting the below error :

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Here is the code snippet using to download the latest file :

```
  def get_most_recent_s3_object(bucket_name, prefix)

       s3 = session.client('s3')
       paginator = s3.get_paginator( "list_objects_v2" )
       page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=prefix, Delimiter="/")
       latest = None
       for page in page_iterator:
           if "Contents" in page:
               latest2 = max(page['Contents'], key=lambda x: x['LastModified'])
               if latest is None or latest2['LastModified'] > latest['LastModified']:
                    latest = latest2
                    with open(latest, 'wb') as f:
                         s3.download_fileobj(bucket_name, latest, 'C:\\Users\xxxx\\)
      return latest
      

  latest = get_most_recent_s3_object(bucket_name='bucket_name_1', prefix='folder_1')
  print(latest['Key'])
```

But I'm not able to download the into my local path. the code is getting latest file from folders inside folders not from the s3-bucket inside folder (folder_1).

Comment: I guess you could set the `Delimiter`  to `"/"` to stop looking into sub-"folders" when calling `paginate`.

Comment: @luk2302, Actually i am new to aws, Could you please help me to download the latest file by updating the code.

Comment: Just add that parameter to the paginator: `page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=prefix, Delimiter="/")`

Comment: @Bert Blommers, I am getting error like : TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable. When i use the Delimiter="/"

Answer (score 1):

I have modified the below code to download the latest file in s3-bucket inside folder and it's working fine. Please find the below working code snippet.

```
def get_most_recent_s3_object(bucket_name, prefix)

   s3 = session.client('s3')
   paginator = s3.get_paginator( "list_objects_v2" )
   page_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=prefix, Delimiter="/")
   latest = None
   for page in page_iterator:
       if "Contents" in page:
           latest2 = max(page['Contents'], key=lambda x: x['LastModified'])
           if latest is None or latest2['LastModified'] > latest['LastModified']:
                latest = latest2.get('Key')
                with open(C:\\Users\xxxx\\dummy.csv', 'wb') as f:
                     s3.download_fileobj(bucket_name, latest, f)
                print('Latest file downloaded successfully....!!!')
  
  

  latest = get_most_recent_s3_object(bucket_name='bucket_name_1', prefix='folder_1/')
```